# Using flume how to stream tweets from twitter only in English language?

Tags: hadoop, twitter, flume

I am trying to stream tweets about Deadpool movie whose are in English and load it to my hdfs.I configure my flume.conf like [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_flume/fetching_twitter_data.htm)

```
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords=Deadpool
```

but It stream all tweets of any language so how I stream tweets only in English laanguage?

Comment: Can you try putting Deadpool lang:en?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like **apache twitter source** and **cloudera twitter source** doesn't have language filtering. As suggested in [this post](http://www.dataprocessingtips.com/2016/04/24/custom-twitter-source-for-apache-flume/) you need to add your own twitter source and run to get the desired results.
You can look at twitter official client [here](https://github.com/twitter/hbc)